# Expresso Store CP Menu

Tags: expresso-store

The system does not appear to have created a CP menu option to get to the store.  Currently I am having to go through Developer, Add ons, Store to see the store dashboard.  Is there a way I can create this button manually?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a button... In EE3 to EE5, Setting -> Menu manager -> Manage your menuset -> Add menu item -> Single Link to your addon-link (you have to copy - paste from the address bar).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have tried that option but it appears only to work during the logged in session. As soon as I log out or the other super admin trys to access we get a log on screen and then right back to the control panel.

Comment: @CecilBridgewater it's possible you're using session IDs in the control panel and copied the session ID when you copied the link. Consider moving the control panel to cookie auth and re-copying the link without the session ID.

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly what the issue was. Appreciate the help